# How can I publish a Simperium note?

Tags: simperium

How can I publish a note using the PublishURL propertie?

```
{"tags": [], "deleted": false, "shareURL": "", "systemTags": [], "content": "updated note with new modification time", "publishURL": "", "modificationDate": 1341563318.0, "creationDate": 1335390338.091453}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The publish functionality still uses the old API currently - you can use the following call to publish a note

```
GET https://simple-note.appspot.com/api2/data/[note key]/publish
```

The response should contain a publishkey:

```
{ "publishkey" : "xdAa5s" }
```

You can use a X-Simperium-Token header like in Simperium to authenticate.